# Output datetime from MySQL with offset

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I'm currently writing to a datetime XML field from MySQL data. The MySQL field is populated with current_timestamp() but this only outputs - **2014-02-18 15:34:02** whereas I need something like **2014-02-14T13:59:33**. Can this be done without hacking the 'T' in there?

Thanks, Ste

Comment: Whats wrong with `REPLACE(column,' ','T')`

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%i:%s')